# Which specific songs are being parodied in this segment from "The Pick Of Destiny"?

Tags: rock, similar-artists

I hope this is eligible question for stack. I don't really know where to go with this, and original Stack Overflow was often helping me with programming questions, therefore - here we go:

There is an amazing movie `Tenatious D and the pick of destiny` here is a culmination rock-off from it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOBKxUT9Da4#t=1m10s

The line which starts on `1.15` `f***, the demon code prevents me...` to around 1.30, this sound and harmony... it sounds painfully similar to... what? It's not just a pain from inability to figure what is it similar to, but also the fact that I really like it and want to hear more, and it seems like the film, being a rock-comedy, totally can parody here a sound of some old-famous-and-great heavy metal band, but which (one or few) - I can not figure it out.

Also from the same movie http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-exiKRZZUuU sound of chorus `Storm the gate!` again causes heavy deja-vu.

So any ideas/suggestions?
Hope i'm not just wasting your time, best regards.

Comment: Wel, it's a 4-5-2 chord progression, which is pretty common throughout music.  And, given that it's written by a very talented duo of musicians (and that specific segment features one of the [most talented musicians of all time](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/41/have-there-been-musicians-who-have-been-in-more-than-one-band-with-a-top-10-hit)), I don't know if it was specifically meant to rip off anyone.

Comment: Yeah, that is absolutely possible, maybe, indeed, it's just a dejavu.
Dave Grohl huh, need to look up his works.

Comment: @JohnnyBones mybe you can share some ideas out of your head about oldschool bands praising similar sound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think my comment above was a bit wrong, it's more like a 5-5-2-3 (aka E-C-D) chord progression.  Here's an example:

[Metallica - Creeping Death breakdown](https://youtu.be/UO_84C3fpuI?t=3m38s)

This is actually 5-2-3-5-3-2, but you get the point.

Another Metallica jam that loosely follows this pattern is the verse sections in their cover of Budgie's [Breadfan](https://youtu.be/9Z6cVUOhLDw?t=39s), although that one is more like 5-5-5-5-5-5-5-5-2-3 (with some chugs and minor almost inaudible fills thrown in for good measure).

Iron Maiden's [Rime of the Ancient Mariner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7zk4as9kzA) also follows this pattern, particularly in the opening riff.  In fact, a **lot** of Steve Harris-penned Iron Maiden songs (including [Running Free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80Hyz4pOXtE)) are written in this fashion.

Extrapolate this over thousands of Metal/Rock songs and you're sure to see that the progression isn't unique.

Comment: Thank you, that an interesting suggestions, in fact, wasn't listening to much of Iron Maiden songs, i always felt that their sound is a bit boring (completely personal preference), maybe it's worth revisiting.

Comment: Iron Maiden's first 2 records are, what I would consider, the first ever Progressive Metal records.  The musicianship was AMAZING.  I wasn't crazy about the vocalist at the time (Paul D'Ianno), but the music was great.